# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 15-17: ord inal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-unicode

I am having a tough time in running the following code.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import re
import csv

file = open("Test.CSV", "r")
reader = csv.reader(file)
for line in reader:
    text = line[5]
    lst = re.findall('(http.?://[^\s]+)', text)

    if not lst: print('Empty List')
    else:
        try:
            for url in lst:
                html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
                title = soup.title.string
                str_title = str (title)
                if 'Twitter' in str_title:
                    if len(lst) > 1: break
                    else: continue
                else:
                    print (str_title, ',', url)
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
            if err.code == 404:
                print ('Invalid Twitter Link')
```

The above mentioned code reads a csv file, selects a column, then parses that using regex to get all the hyperlinks in a single row, I then use BeautifulSoup to parse through the Hyperlink to get the 'Title String' of the page.

Now, whenever i run this code, it stops working for a particular row, and throws an error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 15-17: ordinal not in range(128)"

How do I work my way with the Unicode String here ?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be better to give the exact line of the error along with the full error message and stack trace. In addition, a UnicodeEncodeError suggests that the error occurs at write time (not read time)...

Comment: Here is the exact error:   File "C:\Users\asaxena\Desktop\py4e\Gartner\crawler_new.py", line 29, in <modu
le>
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
  File "C:\Users\asaxena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\re
quest.py", line 223, in urlopen

Comment: File "C:\Users\asaxena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\clie
nt.py", line 1117, in putrequest
    self._output(request.encode('ascii'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 15-17: ord
inal not in range(128)

Comment: The errors would be better in the question itself that in comments (much more readable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message shows that the problem happens in `urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx)`. It looks like at least one of the URLs contains non ASCII characters.

What to do?

You can try to quote the URL:

```
html = urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.parse.quote(url, errors='ignore'), context=ctx).read()
```

This will prevent the `UnicodeEncodeError`, but will silently build an erroneous url which is likely to lead to problems later.

My advice is to catch the UnicodeEncodeError and display an error message that will help to understand what happens under the hood and how to actually fix it:

```
for url in lst:
    try:
        html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        title = soup.title.string
        ...
    except UnicodeEncodeError as e:
        print("Incorrect URL {}".format(url.encode('ascii', errors='backslashreplace')))
```

The `errors='backslashreplace'` option will dump the code of the offending characters

Comment: Great.. Let me try this as well.. BTW, can we have more than 1 Try & Except block in a code, you see I already have a try & except block in my code. Sorry for asking such as basic question, I am quite new to Python.

Comment: Try-except blocks can be nested. An exception will be first handed to the inner block. If it fails to catch it, it will be propagated to the enclosing bloc.

Comment: Hi, I solved this error, but ran into some of the other error, e.g. "urllib.error.URLError", I addressed this one, but then I ran into another one "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asaxena\Desktop\py4e\Gartner\crawler_new.py", line 32, in <modu
le>
    title = soup.title.string
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'". Is there really any way for me to bypass any type of error that appears ? Even the unforseen ones ?